# Simple ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

I am new to ajax and am trying to get the following script working. I just want to take info from a json object and print it to the document.

Here is the JSON file called companyinfo.json:

```
{
'id':1,
'name':'Stack'


}
```

The Ajax request looks like this:

```
ar xhr = false;
var xPos, yPos;

$(function(){

    var submitButton = $("#dostuff");
    submitButton.onclick = sendInfoRequest;

});

function sendInfoRequest (evt) {
    if (evt) {
        var company1 = $("#companyInput1").val;
        var company2 = $("#companyInput2").val;
    }
    else {
        evt = window.event;
        var company = evt.srcElement;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url : 'companyinfo.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: company1,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var items = new Array ();
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
            });
        }

    });


    return false;
}
console.log(data.id);
```

To start simple. I just console.log the data.id to see if the script returned a value from the json file.

To write it to the document I would do something like this, calling the showContents function in the callback function above:

```
function showContents(companyNumber) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            var outMsg = xhr.responseXML;
            $("." + data.companyName.toLowerCase + companyNumber).innerHTML(data.companyName)
        }
        else {
            var outMsg = "There was a problem with the request " + xhr.status;
        }


    }
}
```

I'm pretty new to Ajax, but hopefully that makes some sense. Thanks

Comment: So... whats the problem?

Comment: what should i set the value of company1 to be (aka what should i put in the input field that i submit). and how should the corresponding json document be formatted to reflect that company name? Nothing is happening when i submit that script above

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to get something i think you should add

```
type:"GET"
```

on your $.ajax it should look like this.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'companyinfo.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type:"GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: company1, //What is your purpose for adding this?
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var items = new Array ();
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about this in your code:

```
var company1 = $("#companyInput1").val; //should it be with ()??
var company2 = $("#companyInput2").val; //should it be with ()??
```

should it be with () like this one:

```
var company1 = $("#companyInput1").val();
var company2 = $("#companyInput2").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get and parse JSON is to use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
// you need to use a map as your data => {key : value}
$.getJSON("companyinfo.json", {company : company1}, function(data){
  console.log(data);
  var items = []; // new Array();
  $.each(data, function(key, val){
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
  });
  // do something with items
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
 $.getJSON("getJson.ashx", { Index: 1 }, function (d) {
                    alert(d);
                });
```